# jQuery animation of maxHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

Im trying to animate the height of a div, so it expands to the auto height - i know this isnt possible, which is why i tried with maxHeight. This bugs alot though. Any ideas why? Snippet and jsFiddle included.

Sorry for the messy code 
https://jsfiddle.net/2d6ry1fL/1/

```js
$(".seeMore").click(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
  if (val == "Read more") {
  $(this).parent().animate({maxHeight:"1000px"});
  $(this).text("Read less");
  $(this).siblings('.gradientBox').css('display','none');
} else {
  $(this).parent().animate({maxHeight:"100px"});
  $(this).text("Read more");
  $(this).siblings('.gradientBox').css('display','block');
}
  return false;
  });
```

```css
  .inspArticle {
    width: auto;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    border: 1px solid $tableBorder;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  }
  .more {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  .seeMore {
    position: absolute;
    right: 42px;
    bottom: 12px;
    width: 133px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="inspArticle more">
      <section>
        <article>
          <h3 class="inspHeadline">How to use your new  Brochure</h3>
          <p class="date">21/09/17</p>
          <p>We have just visited your shop and handed you our new brochure. The new Water Utility Range Brochure is presenting our competencies within water supply and wastewater and our product offerings for optimised water solutions.</p>
          <p>At, we are meeting the challenges facing the water supply and wastewater industry head on. The Range Brochure tells how we design lifecycle costs into solutions to make life easier for everyone.</p>
          <p>Use the brochure to inspire you costumers to make a different when choosing products for their work </p>
          <button class="primaryAction">Find brochure</button>
        </article>
      </section>
      <div class="gradientBox"></div>
      <button class="secondaryAction seeMore">Read more</button>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap can do this quite easily if you're open to using it:

https://jsfiddle.net/AP__/pwxk9Ltp/3/

html:

```
<section id="inspArticle" class="collapse in">
  <section>
    <img src="img/grundfosWaterUtilityRangeBrochure.jpg" alt="Grundfos Water Utility Range Brochure">
    <article>
      <h3 class="inspHeadline">How to use your new Grundfos Brochure</h3>
      <p class="date">21/09/17</p>
      <p>We have just visited your shop and handed you our new Grundfos brochure. The new Grundfos Water Utility     Range Brochure is presenting our competencies within water supply and wastewater and our product offerings for     optimised water solutions.</p>
      <p>At Grundfos, we are meeting the challenges facing the water supply and wastewater industry head on. The     Range Brochure tells how we design lifecycle costs into solutions to make life easier for everyone.</p>
      <p>Use the brochure to inspire you costumers to make a different when choosing products for their work </p>
      <button class="primaryAction">Find brochure</button>
        </article>
  </section>
  <div class="gradientBox"></div>
</section>
<a class="secondaryAction" data-toggle='collapse' href='#inspArticle'>Read Less</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

js:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("a.secondaryAction").text('Read Less');
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("a.secondaryAction").text('Read More');
});
```

Also don't forget to include the bootstrap css

Comment: I dont like the thought of using bootstrap, to be honest. But if it is the only solution, it might be neccessary

Comment: You could always look into the bootstrap js and css files and extract out the 'collapse' code